# Web Inspector crashed in Safari 7

Tags: safari, macos

When I try to display web inspector just a grey background shows instead of that. I tried to restart browser but it didn't help. It happens in Safary 7 OS X Mavericks.

Anybody knows what is that could be?

Comment: I used the window resizing and that helped. Currently I have another issue. There is still no content in WI but resizing doesn't help. I tried to reopen WI again and that helped. So I've added an (i) button to the toolbar to do it quickly. Safari is a wonderful browser )

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix that brought the inspector back for me was to resize the web inspector pane by moving the mouse to the top edge until the pointer changed to the resizing pointer and dragging.

Answer (score 0):

A reboot seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Solution (works permanent, without reboot):

Open Terminal:
`killall -KILL Dock`

This is Dock restart.

EDIT:

Also you can make alias in ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile, for fast run of this cmd.

`alias dockrestart="killall -KILL Dock"`

Comment: What does killing the Dock have to do with Safari's Web Inspector? I tried this since I'm having the same issue and it made no difference.

Comment: I dunno. For me it works fine. Tried 1 minute ago.

Comment: Coincidence maybe? The Dock is just an app (`/System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app`). I don't see how killing it would (or could) have any effect on Safari.

Comment: For me it works, because when my dock is hidden i have no any bugs with Web Inspector. So Dock restart is very useful for me. p.s. Mavericks installed into clean drive. I think apple must debug it all.